# Trouble representing an equation

Tags: equation-solving

I'm having trouble representing the following as an equation

```
 Ids[Vgs_,Vds_,Vtn_,kn_] := \[Piecewise]    0   Vgs < Vtn
                             kn * ((Vgs-Vtn) * Vds - 1/2 * Vds^2)   Vgs >= Vtn && Vds < Vgs - Vtn
                             kn/2* (Vgs - Vtn)^2    Vgs >= Vtn && Vds >= Vgs - Vtn




 ModeOfOperation[Vgs_, Vds_, Vtn_, kn_] := \[Piecewise] "Cutoff"    Vgs < Vtn
                                                         "Triode"   Vgs >= Vtn && Vds < Vgs - Vtn
                                                         "Saturation"   Vgs>= Vtn && Vds >= Vgs - Vtn




 Rd = 0.2
Vin = 5
eq1 = Ids[Vin, V0, 1 , 1] = (5 - 2 - V0)/Rd

Solve[eq1, V0] // N
```

I've already defined `Rd =.2` and `Vin = 5`. But I get the following error:

> "5.(3-V0) is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities."

and

> "5(3. -1.V0) is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities"

Why is `eq1` not a valid expression? I understand what I'm trying to do is use the values for Vin, Rd and select the right equation from the piecewise for the left side and then solve for V0 using the right hand side.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Try to use == instead of =

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html

Comment: I tried eq1 = Ids[Vin,V0,1,1] == (5-2-V0)/Rd but its just returning True...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Piecewise functions should be written as follows

```
Ids[Vgs_, Vds_, Vtn_, kn_] :=
  Piecewise[{
    {0, Vgs < Vtn},
    {kn*((Vgs - Vtn)*Vds - 1/2*Vds^2), Vgs >= Vtn && Vds < Vgs - Vtn},
    {kn/2*(Vgs - Vtn)^2, Vgs >= Vtn && Vds >= Vgs - Vtn}}];

ModeOfOperation[Vgs_, Vds_, Vtn_, kn_] :=
  Piecewise[{
    {"Cutoff", Vgs < Vtn},
    {"Triode", Vgs >= Vtn && Vds < Vgs - Vtn},
    {"Saturation", Vgs >= Vtn && Vds >= Vgs - Vtn}}];

Rd = 0.2;
Vin = 5;
eq1 = Ids[Vin, V0, 1, 1] == (5 - 2 - V0)/Rd;

Solve[eq1, V0][[1]]
```

> {V0 -> 1.85857}

Comment: Thanks. I'm still learning Mathematica and the "scoping" (right side blue line) was also a huge source of my issues but I finished my assignment. Thank you for your help. Marius too.

Answer (score 0):

An equation is of the form `lhs == rhs`. When you write `eq1 = (5 - 2 - V0)/Rd` you just set the "value" of  `eq1`.

Comment: I've taken a look at http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EliminatingVariables.html but setting eq1 = Ids[Vin,V0,1,1] == (5-2-V0)/Rd just returns true for the above code and not the value for V0.